# How to add parentheses to column values in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, parentheses

I'm working with sensitive data, so I created a fake data frame that can serve as an example. This is what we're working with.

```
n    percent
4     36%
5     51%
6     61%
7     71%
8     84%
9     96%
10    100%
```

Pretty simple. I want to change the percent column so that the values have parentheses around them. So essentially, I want the data frame to look like this:

```
n  Percent
4   (36%)
5   (51%)
6   (61%)
```

I realize that this will make it a string, but that's not a problem for my ultimate purposes. I wrote a function that returns the column as a vector with parentheses.

`addparentheses <- function(x){paste("(", x, ")")}`

`addparentheses (sample_data$percent)`

`[1] "( 36% )"  "( 51% )"  "( 61% )"  "( 71% )"  "( 84% )"  "( 96% )"  "( 100% )"`

How can I write something like this so that it actually changes the data frame and doesn't just return a vector?

Any ideas and insights are much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Why not `sample_data$percent <- addparentheses(sample_data$percent)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
x <- tibble(
  n = 4:10,
  pct = paste0(4:10, "%")
)

x <- x %>%
  mutate(pct = paste0("(", pct, ")"))
```

Or in base R

```
x$pct <- paste0("(", x$pct, ")")
```